# How to calculate mean between sequential sorted elements

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe`, and I need to calculate the mean between sequential elements (`time_ref`)

(mean between to elements from same `f_idx` after sorting by `time_ref` column).

I want to group by `f_idx` and print the results

for example:

```
   f_idx  time_ref
0    f1    5
1    f2    7
2    f3    2
3    f2    4
4    f1    1
5    f1    9
6    f2    8
```

expected output:

```
   f_idx  res_mean
0    f1    mean((5-1), (9-5))
1    f2    mean((7-4), (8-7))
2    f3    Nan  (just one element, so there is not diff)
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: How is this data stored? A data frame? Lists? Dict?

Comment: dataframe (pandas)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way with [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) , with [`df.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) on `axis=1` and `df.mean` on `axis=1`:

```
df = df.sort_values('time_ref')
s = df.groupby('f_idx').cumcount()

out =( df.set_index(['f_idx',s])['time_ref'].unstack().diff(axis=1).mean(1)
      .reset_index(name='output'))
```

---

```
print(out)

  f_idx  output
0    f1     4.0
1    f2     2.0
2    f3     NaN
```

Comment: I'm getting error (unstack function): ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: @user3668129 do you set other columns as index? the code works fine for me with your question's example

Answer (score 1):

First sort values by both columns and then aggregate by lambda function with [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) and `mean`:

```
df1 = df.sort_values(['f_idx','time_ref'], ascending=[True,False])

df2 = (df1.groupby('f_idx')['time_ref'].agg(lambda x: x.diff(-1).mean())
          .reset_index(name='res_mean'))

print (df2)
  f_idx  res_mean
0    f1       4.0
1    f2       2.0
2    f3       NaN
```

Comment: @anky - testing ;)

Comment: @anky - for me working correctly. Maybe `df.sort_values('time_ref')` should be first step and then your solution. Because maybe some index mismatch (only idea, without real data hard debugging)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `groupby` twice:

```
df = (df
      .sort_values(['f_idx','time_ref'], ascending=[True,False])
      .groupby('f_idx')
      ['time_ref']
      .rolling(2)                                  # Take every 2 items
      .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] - x.iloc[1])      # Get the difference
      .groupby('f_idx')
      .mean()                                      # Get the mean
      .rename('res_mean')
      .to_frame())
```

The result you wanted:

```
f_idx   res_mean
f1  4.0
f2  2.0
f3  NaN
```

Comment: I'm getting error: numpy.ndarray objet has not attribute iloc

Comment: if I'm removing the rolling(2) I'm not getting error. What am I missing ?

Comment: what is your `pandas` version?

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

p = [
     ['f1',5],
     ['f2',7],
     ['f3',2],
     ['f2',4],
     ['f1',1],
     ['f1',9],
     ['f2',8]
     ]
p1=sorted(p,reverse=True) #sort reverse
p2=p1[1:] #move to the left
d = [[p1[n][0],  
    p1[n][1]-p2[n][1] if p1[n][0]==p2[n][0] else np.nan
    ] for n in range(len(p2))] #differences

d=pd.DataFrame(d)
d.columns=['f_idx','res_mean']
d.groupby('f_idx').mean()
```

Out[230]:

```
f_idx   res_mean    
f1          4.0    
f2          2.0    
f3          NaN
```